# Foreach error when field empty

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

When the checkboxes field has data, no error.
When the checkboxes field has no data, this debug error:

Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/1/wp-content/themes/understrap-child-master/loop-templates/content-single-networks.php on line 152
Array,

Here is the display checkboxes code:

```
<?php $pays = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'net_payment', false );
    if ($pays) {
        echo "<tr><td class='tdlable'>Paymentddd</td><td class='tditem'>";
        foreach ($pays as $pay ) {
         echo $pay . ", ";
         } ;
        echo "</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Any ideas? And do I need to add a reset? This is on a single.php page.

Comment: You should use the implode function.

Comment: Share what you get in `$pays`?

Comment: On a post where pays is not null I see:  ACH, Alipay, Bitcoin, Check, Debit Card, Digital Currency, EPayments, Paxum, Payoneer, Paypal, Skrill, Webmoney, Wire,  On a page where the field is empty I get this error: Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/1/wp-content/themes/understrap-child-master/loop-templates/content-single-networks.php on line 152
Array,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter is false so it will give you result as an array. So you can change your condition like below to avoid notice:

```
if(!empty($pays)) { // YOUR CODE }
```

or another option is if you have a single value then you can set third parameter as true like:

```
$pays = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'net_payment', true );
```

and then do your code without `foreach` to avoid extra code:

```
if ($pays != "") {
      echo "<tr><td class='tdlable'>Paymentddd</td><td class='tditem'>";
         echo $pay . ", ";
        echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Hope this will helpful for you. Thanks.